# How can i redirect a url without controller in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, redirect

I would like to redirect http://valessentia.com/de to [http://valessentia.com](http://valessentia.com/).
I tried the that:

```
valessentia_de:
    pattern: /de
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /
        permanent: true
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your .htaccess file inside the /web directory add following line after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

add

```
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've solved my problem with this:
    Redirect temp /de/ http://valessentia.com/
    Redirect temp /de http://valessentia.com/

Answer (score 0):

If i go to `valessentia.de` i'am redirected to `/de` so its working. The problem ist now that all your other routes aren't working because you have no language in your route.

When you click on a link you get an 404. Here is a short exmaple for a routing that includes the language:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/hello
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:hello, _locale: en}
```

Comment: As I see it he wants to redirect `.com/de` to `.com` not `.de` to `.com/de`. Looks like stripping the default locale is the goal

Comment: @ferdynator Yes that's it. Any advice on how i can do that?